# How to build an .apk in release mode with mobile first cli and cordova

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm using MFP Fondation 7.1 to develop an android hybrid application with :

```
mfp cordova create
```

But i wonder how to build my .apk with no emulator or device?

Is there an other way than :

```
mfp cordova run
mfp cordova emulate
```

?

And is there a way to build in release mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building an apk is not related to MFP or CLI or Cordova.
It is related to Android Studio or Google's ADT command line tooling, which is in charge of creating the .apk.

Install either of them and use the provided tooling within those, to create an .apk.